# user level based template filtering

Tags: php, joomla

I am developing Joomla component and we have a lot of user based functionality. I got tired of writting if's to filter which parts to show for user so I decided to write some sort of script to make it easier. So my goal is to achieve something like this templating structure:

```
<div id="my-component-root">
    <div class="common-content">
    </div>
    <!--{if[admin]}-->
    <div class="admin-content">
    </div>
    <!--{endif[admin]}-->

    <!--{if[captain]}-->
    <div class="captain-content">
    </div>
    <!--{endif[captain]}-->
</div>
```

So resulting template would be preprocessed and template that would be generated and passed to a view. (here is what would be result for normal user)

```
<div id="my-component-root">
    <div class="common-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is what **would be easiest way to achieve such template preprocessing?**

EDIT:

would be like normal opening if tag except that it would allow easy way to compile template for exact usertype like regular user. In this way I wouldn't need to edit several scripts to change code accross site..

Comment: `<div class="<?=$userLevel;?>-content">`

Comment: How would it help to get rid of unwanted code from template?

Comment: Your view should have requesting from the model a userLevel() function for example which return i.e. admin stored in $userLevel variable. You are using the output in the class name to show this div. You can prevent opening other div classes with one single if `(!$userLevel)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really depends on how your HTML is built, what information do you really store and how sensitive it is.

If you have for example:

```
<div id="my-component-root">
    <div class="common-content">
    </div>
    <!--{if[admin]}-->
    <div class="admin-content">
        Welcome %User, You have logged in as Administrator
    </div>
    <!--{endif[admin]}-->

    <!--{if[captain]}-->
    <div class="captain-content">
        Hello, you are not Administrator.
    </div>
    <!--{endif[captain]}-->
</div>
```

So, the user came here with userlevel=captain and the `div` is loaded with captain-content and vice versa. Everything is static, but also is bunch of code.

You have another chance to put the texts onEvent where class is present. So you can build class dynamically and load content on the built class as @Friend and Me already written in answer and comment. This way is more unsecure if you have sensitive content. Because someone can edit your HTML and recieve the content depending on the class name.

In modern architectures the content is neither static or written in the source. For example, if you logic contains userLevel logic, it means you don't only want to salute them with either "Hello admin", or "Hello user", but also to load certain options which are allowed for admins and disallowed for users.

This way you need several things:

- Separate the features which are allowed for admins in files i.e.: admin_edit_profile.php ...
- Make a method which allows text building (translation method) on given placeholder
- Make a security check in the included files where the level() is passed to admin_profile.php so there should be smth like `if ($userLevel != 'admin') die())`
- ** Let's assume you have class UserLevel with method `roles()` which give what can anyone do on which role is assigned i.e. if admin he can `edit_profile`. And method `level()` where return the level (admin, user...) **

Now you can have:

```
<div id="my-component-root">
    <div class="common-content">
    </div>
    <?php foreach($userLevel->roles() as $role):
    <div class="<?=$userLevel->level();?>-content">
        <?php require_once "$userLevel->level()" . "_" . "$role" . ".php"; ?>
        <?= __('placeholder_text_for_translation_for_role' . $role); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now you can store the content of the translated i.e. `placeholder_text_for_translation_for_role_edit_profile` in a database and return its translation (english text) right after the include.

This way you will have included file with options for administrators profile edit

```
<?php require_once "admin_edit_profile.php"; ?>
```

And text for it

```
<?= "Here you can edit user profiles"; ?>
```

So the whole content built will be:

```
<div id="my-component-root">
    <div class="common-content">
    </div>
    <div class="admin-content">
        <?php require_once "admin_edit_profile.php"; ?>
        <?= "Here you can edit user profiles"; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: I havent thought of autoloading actual script, content will be sensitive because as I said we have backend functions for administration in front end as extended functionality for administrators. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Yeah i'm wondering why you don't just use the core ACL to manage this. That's what it is there for.  Why

Answer (score 1):

@insanebits check the code below..

```
<div id="my-component-root">
    <div class="common-content">
    </div>

    <div class="<?=$userLevel;?>-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

where `$userLevel` can be admin or normal user or moderator , based on the class name will change ... and to achive this you should have separate template for `admin/user/moderator` i have enhanced Royal Bg suggestion....

Comment: Sorry but my purpose is to actually remove content from my code. Your solution would only apply different styles according to a user level. In my case I would want to completely remove some functionality for regular user because in our project backend is mixed with frontend..

Comment: So it's controllers logic. Requesting the page `x.php` will render template `user.php` when userLevel='user' or will render template `admin.php` when userLevel='admin'. You have no other choice, you need casing, whether it's on template level with bunch of content or on rendering level

Comment: ya Royal Bg is absolutely correct.....if you are trying to achive it by template level your `template content` increases... its better you try in controller level....

Comment: In such way code is hard to maintain, thats why I need to keep actual code in single file and precompile it dividing files into user.php and admin.php see my edited question.

Comment: Why don't you assign access levels to your content and then only people with access will see it. Look at Kunena or similar that has a lot of front end administration.